# How does free baggage for Frequent Traveler status work?

Tags: luggage, loyalty-programs, miles-and-more

I have gained Frequent Traveler status with Miles & More on my last travel. One of the benefits is additional free baggage.

From [Miles & More status comparison](https://www.miles-and-more.com/de/en/program/status-benefits/status-level-comparison.html):

> Total amount of free baggage
>
> Piece concept: 1 additional piece of baggage in Economy Class, a total of 2 pieces in Premium Economy Class and Business Class, 3 pieces in First Class

Do I have to do something specific to use that free allowance? Does it have to be registered or booked before or do I just show my M&M card at check-in?

I have booked a flight (economy class) with no checked luggage before I gained the status, but my flight is in future. Can I still have 1 piece of free checked luggage?

Comment: What airline and what fare is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Beware of Fare-Dependent Frequent Traveller Benefits

Be sure to check that the Miles & More partner airline allows you to use Frequent Traveller benefits on the flight class and ticket fare you have purchased. See for example [Brussels Airlines](https://www.brusselsairlines.com/en-hr/practical-information/allowances-fees/extra-allowance-frequent-flyer.aspx), which has a fare-dependent benefit scheme for Frequent Traveller status:

[image: Brussels Airlines fare-dependent frequent traveller benefits]

This is part of the Miles & More terms and conditions. Quoting from the [linked Miles & More page](https://www.miles-and-more.com/row/en/program/status-benefits/status-level-comparison.html):

> Piece concept: 1 additional piece of baggage in Economy Class, a total of 2 pieces in Premium Economy Class and Business Class, 3 pieces in First Class<sup>12</sup>

The fineprint says:

> <sup>12</sup> On scheduled flights operated by Adria Airways, Austrian Airlines, Croatia Airlines, Lufthansa, Lufthansa Private Jet and SWISS, the following applies: 2 pieces of baggage each up to 23 kg (Economy), 2 pieces of baggage each up to 23 kg (Premium Economy), 2 pieces of baggage each up to 32 kg (Business), 3 pieces of baggage each up to 32 kg (First). The additional free baggage or golf bag allowance has ceased for the Light fare category on European and intercontinental Economy Class flights operated by Austrian Airlines, Lufthansa, and SWISS. The additional free baggage or golf bag allowance has ceased for the BASIC fare in Economy Class on flights operated by Adria Airways within Europe. The additional free baggage or golf bag allowance has ceased for the FlyEasy fare in Economy Class on the flights operated by Croatia Airlines. On flights operated by Brussels Airlines, the following applies: 0 pieces of baggage (Check&Go, short-haul flights), 2 pieces of baggage up to 23 kg (Light&Relax and Flex&Fast, short-haul flights and Economy Class, Premium Economy, long-haul flights to/from USA and Tel Aviv), 3 pieces of baggage up to 23 kg (Economy Class, long-haul flights to/from Africa), 2 pieces of baggage up to 32 kg (Bizz&Class, short-haul flights and Business Class, long-haul flights). On flights operated by LOT Polish Airlines, the following applies: 1 piece of baggage up to 23 kg (Economy Class Saver), 2 pieces of baggage up to 23 kg (Economy; short and long-haul flights), 2 pieces of baggage up to 23 kg (Premium Economy Class, long-haul flights), 2 pieces of baggage up to 32 kg (Business, short-haul flights) and 3 pieces of baggage up to 32 kg (Business, long-haul flights). On flights operated by Luxair, the following applies: 1 additional piece of baggage up to 23 kg or 1 golf bag (Economy), 1 additional piece of baggage up to 32 kg or 1 golf bag (Business).

You will notice that, being the first milestone of the program does not give Frequent Traveller status holders that many benefits. I know, I am one of them.

#### How Do I Use the Extra Luggage Benefit?

> Do I have to do something specific to use that free allowance? Does it have to be registered or booked before or do I just show my M&M card at check-in?

If you book the flight as a registered user with an updated Miles & More card showing your status, then your baggage allowance should appear on the booking page. Otherwise, you will need to show your card at the check-in desk to be able to use your allowance.

> I have booked a flight (economy class) with no checked luggage before I gained the status, but my flight is in future. Can I still have 1 piece of free checked luggage?

Yes. If on the date of the flight your fare includes luggage and your newly acquired status allows you to have extra luggage, you will be able to use this advantage.

Comment: Your answer to the last question (`I have booked a flight (economy class) with no checked luggage`) contradicts your previous quotes. If he booked a fare with no checked luggange, it can only be one of the Light, Check&Go and whatever named fares, where, as a FTL, you don't get any free checked luggage.

Comment: @dunni Partially yes. The quote from Brussels Airlines is solely an example. I do not know which airline OP is flying with. I'll edit for clarification.